# ¿Importar un paquete completo o importar clase por clase Java?

Tags: java, buenas-prácticas

Cuál es la mejor forma de importar varias clases de un mismo paquete.
La más fácil es importar todo el paquete, aunque aquí pueden importarse clases que no se necesitan.

```
import mipaquete.foo.*
```

La otra forma es más larga pero solamente importaría lo que necesite:

```
import mipaquete.foo.Clase1
import mipaquete.foo.Clase2
// Otras clases importadas aquí.
import mipaquete.foo.Clase5
```

¿A la hora del rendimiento afecta que se importe todo el paquete con clases que no se ocupan?

Comment: Aquí podrás encontrar alguna de las opiniones referentes a tu duda:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187453/import-package-vs-import-package-specifictype

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema podría surgir al hacer referencia a todo el contenido del paquete (usando *), cuando tengas clases con el mismo nombre que existen en diferentes paquetes, esto podría ocasionar un problema el cual no permitiría compilar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para resolver este problema se requiere precisamente que se especifique completamente cualquier nombre de clase o interfaz que sea ambiguo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> ¿A la hora del rendimiento afecta que se importe todo el paquete con
>   clases que no se ocupan?

En realidad no hay alguna afectación al rendimiento, especificando la importación de las clases en el paquete contra la importación de una clase especifica en el paquete, ya que la importación está relacionada únicamente con la compilación.

Importante comentar que en el lenguaje `Java`, el uso de `import` no produce ["code bloat"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_inflado), ya que en realidad no incluye clases no usadas a la aplicación.

Es sin duda una buena practica especificar siempre las clases usadas en tu proyecto para evitar ambigüedad, evitando importar todos los tipos contenidos en un paquete usando la instrucción de importación con el carácter comodín asterisco (*).

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo importar clase por clase.
Al importar todas con * , no estás penalizado el rendimiento de la aplicación (el cargador de clases carga todo el .jar) pero estás incrementando el tamaño de la clase innecesariamente y puedes penalizar a la lectura/mantenimiento del código.

Comment: import no produce "code bloat", en realidad no incluye clases no usadas a la aplicación.